# What is the best test to use?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I am working on a project in my R introductory course but I really dont know what statistical test to use.

I got my data from the Malaria Atlas Project.

I want to know if the the **Use of insecticide treated nets** (Proportion of population that sleeps under a Insecticide treated net during a defined year) and **Use rate** (Proportion of people Sleeping under an insecticide treated net, among those with acces to an insecticide treated net in their household during a defined year) affect the **Incidence rate** (The number of newly diagnosed malaria cases pero 1,000 population during a defined year) or the **Mortality Rate** ( The number of deaths from malaria pero 100,000 population during defined year). The data is from 2010 to 2020.

I really dont have a strong background in statistics (i can understan simple linear regression, t test and ANOVA) so Im having real problems defining the correct test for this situation. I tried to google it but without a guide i dont even know where to start.

Comment: You probably need a nonlinear multilevel model, which is far too advanced for what you know. So, either choose some other goal or, just do a lot of graphs, as Harvey recommends. That will be good practice, graphs are used all the time, they ought to be part of just about every statistical project.

Comment: I think you need to simplify what you're doing. Focus on one outcome and one predictor. Something as simple as a proportion test may work if you structure it correctly. (I'm not sure if you can if the the data you're using is aggregated.) First get the question and variables of focus cleaned up. This is for an intro course, so you don't need to be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

My advice for beginning your explorations: Forget about statistical tests, and graph the data in various ways with as much detail as is reasonable.

Comment: My first guess was using multiple regression. I want to know if this continuos variables (Use and Use rate) have an effect in Incidence rate (lets forget about mortality rate for a minute). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Regression is something you could do. After doing Exploratory Data Analysis with scatter plots and such you can decide which specific regression model you should go with but basically you will be looking something like $$\small(\boldsymbol{User\_rate,Use\_of\_insecticide\_treated\_nets})\sim\boldsymbol{Incidence\_rate+Mortality\_rate}$$. But we are only making a predictive model so we cant do causal analysis as far as I am aware.